# How do I get Eclipse to look in the build path for JSP includes instead of the web source?

Tags: eclipse, jsp, include

We have a portion of our Dynamic Web Application that gets unpacked from a WAR, and placed in the build directory during compile. Because some of the files included in the web source are references to files from that WAR, then Eclipse can't find them. How do I get Eclipse to look instead in my build directory for the include files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not caused by Eclipse. As for every normal request URL, the URL in the `page` attribute of the `<jsp:include>` should just match any of the `url-pattern`-s definied in webapp's or servletcontainer's `web.xml` to be able to get a resource. In your case you just need to define a servlet which gets the [resource from the classpath](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) and [streams](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/io/bytestreams.html) it to the [outputstream of the response](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#getOutputStream%28%29) and map this servlet with an `url-pattern` in `web.xml` which in turn can be used by `<jsp:include>`.

Comment: It uses the include directive, not the jsp:include tag. Does that make a difference for Eclipse?

Comment: No, that's not possible as it will be executed during compile time. It should then really be available in the webcontent. Right now it's only available in the classpath. Oh, don't focus too much on Eclipse. It's just a development tool :)